# Solution for easy generating rest services?

Tags: java, sql, database, web-services, rest

We have a application which works with MySql database.
Now we are implementing mobile version of our application and I'm looking for java solution for easy generating rest services from already ready sql queries.

Details on security and performance: 
Security is required (LDAP).
Performance - working time of rest request should be approximately equals working time of sql request.

What solutions can be used for it?

Comment: What aobut the security or performance?

Comment: updated details on perfomance and security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is [REST4Enterprise](http://www.exadel.com/web/portal/r4e) 
also can take a look on and [restSQL](http://restsql.org/doc/Overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using  [spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) very easy to use

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But  spring roo is a kinda of  utility program and I'm looking for a ready solution (Full Packaged Product).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using netbeans to generate rest webservices from database tables.
Netbeans also offers the ability to generate REST webservices from entity beans (JPA entities).
Have a look at [this link](http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/04/restfulws.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Frankly speaking I'm looking for easy (with minimum of manual efforts) UI level solution. Cons of your approach:dependecy on Netbeans.

Comment: Do you have any preference on an IDE? Or maybe you don't want to use anyone of them?

Comment: Well. In details, I do not want to run any IDE and I do not want to write even a small piece of code.Instead, I'd like to find ready solution to work in

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just CRUD REST services - one of the above tools suggested by others can help.

But for something more check - [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/)

my 2c

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Dropwizard - is a developer's tool, and I'm looking for a kinda ready FPP (Full Packaged Product).

Answer (score 1):

For Mobile applications, REST is the best recommended architecture.  But you have to ensure the session handling at the client side (recommended).

Eclipse -> Webservice -->Create a Sample Rest Webservice will be a good starting point

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well , not that exactly. for easy (with minimum of manual efforts) UI level solution. The approach you described implies manual detailed work, using webservices and correspondingly app redeploy on adding ws and dependency on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring-rest or grails to develop rest services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cons: as I mentioned in the comment above, a lot of manual activities, and adding web service requires application redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing web services in PHP.  No need for anything other than Tomcat, and offers LDAP verification.  It is very quick time to market, and PHP works with MySql pretty seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Frankly speaking I'm looking for easy (with minimum of manual efforts) UI level solution.

Comment: Then I believe PHP is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at [Developing REST Web Services Tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/).. not sure if it's the best solution but could be one... I used it twice and found it usefull and really easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But it is kinda of documentation, but not a even a tool.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java™ world, you can build a RESTful web service in several ways: Some folks use JSR 311(JAX-RS) and its reference implementation Jersey, others use the Restlet framework, and some might even implement from scratch. Spring framework for building Java EE applications, also supports REST in its MVC layer.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html

Below article also covers RESTful web services api using java and mysql

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html